# GCC C++ - How to use __attribute__((packed))

Tags: c++, gcc, attributes, c++20, unions

There is the following union giving the option to variable on per-bit-basis and as the whole using the raw value:

```
union properties {
    struct {
        uint8_t b0 : 1;
        uint8_t b1 : 1;
        uint8_t b2 : 1;
        uint8_t v0 : 3;
        uint8_t b4 : 1;
    } bits;
    uint8_t raw : 7;
};
```

As the properties has direct relation to HW, I really need to avoid any compiler influence like padding in within those structs. So I am about to use GCC's `__attribute__((packed))`.

My question is where to place it in my example? Shall I classify the `bits`:

```
union properties {
    struct {
        ...
    }__attribute__((packed)) bits;
    uint8_t raw : 7;
};
```

or the `properties` struct itself:

```
union properties {
    struct {
        ...
    } bits;
    uint8_t raw : 7;
}__attribute__((packed));
```

or both?

```
union properties {
    struct {
        ...
    } __attribute__((packed)) bits;
    uint8_t raw : 7;
}__attribute__((packed));
```

Is there any rule to use that correctly? Thanks in advace for help and explanation...

BTW: Is that the only way to force the compiler to assemble a packed structure or there is some C++20 standard way to achieve the same?

Comment: You can't pack it smaller than 1 byte if that's what you're asking and from what I can see, it'll be 1 byte without even packing it. There is no need for padding in the `struct` or `union`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo It was just an example, I have the same problem on multiple places in my source code so this was a pure example. I am usually packing 12Bytes. It is rather a question of principle where to correctly set the attribute...

Comment: I see. It's applied where you put it. Here setting it on none, one or both doesn't matter. Perhaps if you make another example where packing matters will it be clearer.